# Autovivification in Vue?

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm transitioning from AngularJS 1.0 to Vue and one feature I'm missing a lot is the Autovivification feature of Angular, i.e. if I set this

```
<input type="text" ng-model="obj.key1.key2.key3.key4">
```

Then as soon as I enter some value in the text-field Angular automatically creates the nested Object for me inside `obj`, i.e. `obj.key1.key2.key3.key4 = value`

*(Vue2 on the other hand throws an error in console: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'key2' of undefined"`)*

**1. Is it possible to do in Vue? If not, why is the feature missing?**

Similarly, if some nested key doesn't exists it Angular doesn't throw warnings like Vue but waits for me to create the object and it starts showing up as soon as the nested key is created

```
  var obj = {}; //controller

  View: {{obj.key1.key2}} //doesn't throw error in Angular but shows warning in Vue
```

**2. Is there some setting for enabling the lenient mode this in Vue?**

*I understand that Angular and Vue are two very different frameworks*, but then there is a lot of similarities (like v-model, v-for, etc) so just wondering why this is different and if it can be same or if there is a reason behind not having this?

Comment: It seems to me that this is related to key difference - absence analog of $scope.$apply in Vue. Vue wraps all model data to tracks changes, while angular do nothing with your model keeping it as is. Thats why you should create model in Vue before view, while in angular you can do it in whatever order. May be mistaken though.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov That does make sense but Vue does keep track of the nested keys as they are created inside the object, so Autovivification shouldn't cause any issues with that. I guess not throwing errors for missing nested keys is also quite useful because sometimes you don't define properties for things that are not needed, i.e. in my case there is no need to create a `shadow` object unless the user ticks the `shadowEnabled` textbox.